# Angular read valueChanges of dynamically added form element in dynamically added grid rows

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a grid in which when I enable edit mode each row become editable. Each row will have some fields for example dropdowns, input fields.
I have a requirement where when I change the dropdown value to a specific value, then only the input field should enable for editing, otherwise it should be disabled. Below is part of code

.ts

```
public editRows(grid: GridComponent) {
        let currentRow = 0;
        let rows = grid.data;

        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          this.formGroup = this.createFormGroup(rows[i]);
          (this.formGroups.get('items') as FormArray).push(this.formGroup);
          
          grid.editRow(currentRow, this.formGroup, {skipFocus: true});
          currentRow++;
          
          
        if(this.formGroup.controls.dataType.value !== 'Value List') {
            this.formGroup.get('inputValues').disable();
          }

          this.formGroup.get('dataType').valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue  => {
            if(selectedValue !== 'Value List') {
                this.formGroup.get('inputValues').disable();
              } else {
                this.formGroup.get('inputValues').enable();
              }
         }); 

        }
     }
```

This editRows function is called when I clicked on edit button in my HTML. Each row in the grid will become editable, but when I try to call valueChanges like in my code, only last row fields are getting affected no matter in which row I am doing editing. I am not really getting how can I exactly reach the current row and it's fields here. Any suggestions will be appeciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**not** use `this.formGroup`, use simply

```
const formGroup=this.createFormGroup()
....
formGroup.get('dataType').susbcribe(...)
```

But I suggest another approach that is that your function createFromGroup create the formGroup that was susbcribe the change. Somelike:

```
createFormGroup(data:any=null){
  data=data || {dataType:null,inputValues:null}
  const group=new FormGroup({
     dataType:new FormControl(data.dataType)
     inputValues:new FormControl(data.inputValues)
  })
  group.get('dataType').valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue=>{
       if(selectedValue !== 'Value List')
          group.get('inputValues').disabled();
       else
          group.get('inputValues').enabled();
  })
  return group
}
```

And you simple use

```
this.formGroups.get('items') as FormArray).push(
     this.createFormGroup(rows[i])
)
```

Else you need "get" the input using some like